# The problem about cross-env NODE_OPTIONS in package.json

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a problem when writing a package.json file to set environment variables
Here is my json file

```
{
   "name": "design-pattern",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
       "start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--trace-deprecation --abort-on-uncaught-exception' ts-node ./src/index.ts",
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
   },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "devDependencies": {
      "@tsconfig/node20": "^20.1.2",
      "@types/node": "^20.10.4",
      "tslib": "^2.6.2",
      "typescript": "^5.3.3"
   },
   "dependencies": {
   "cross-env": "^7.0.3"
   }
}
```

The problem is that when I use "npm run start" to run my index.ts
There is an error message that confuses me:
--abort-on-uncaught-exception' is not recognized as an internal and external command

When I remove one of the flag, for example, "start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--trace-deprecation' or "start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--abort-on-uncaught-exception'
Then, there is no such problem and it works.

So, It seems that it doesn't accept more than one flags
I wonder how to rewrite the statement so that I can set these two flags.

Note:
my npm version: 10.2.0
my node.js version: 20.8.1
my operating system: windows 11 (I use cross-env to solve the problem that NODE_OPTIONS can't be recognized as an internal and external command in my windows OS environment)

To check whether --trace-deprecation and --abort-on-uncaught-exception works, I test whether
"start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--trace-deprecation' or "start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--abort-on-uncaught-exception' work and both of them work fine

I want "start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--trace-deprecation --abort-on-uncaught-exception' to work fine but it fails